# Getting values from radio button in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to get the values from  (male or female)  each pair of radio buttons which are displayed in a `for-loop`.

```
<?php
echo '<form method="post" action="index.php">';
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){

    echo 'Male <input type="radio" name="gender[]" value="Male">Female <input type="radio" name="gender[]" value="Female"><br>';
}
echo '<input type="submit" value="submit" name="test"></form>

?>
```

Also i  am placing a button in which user can add more fields according to his needs

```
<input type="button" value="add" name="">
```

When click on this button pair of "Male" and "female" `radio-button` is added to current form its already implemented .

But how can I get the values with `checked` radio buttons?

Comment: You need to set the values e.g.: `<input type="radio" name="gender[]" value="Enter value">`. Then you need to extract the posted value on the server-side because it's an array.

Comment: But only one radio button is checkd ,cant check more than one radio button

Comment: Because all of them are having same `name`

Comment: There can be only one selected radio button for the same name. If you like to select more, you should use `checkbox` instead.

Comment: @RiggsFolly  which is in the forloop

Comment: Yea, I just realised what you were actually doing. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to collect the Gender of 4 different people you will have to name the radio buttons differently for each person

Using the loop counter would allow you to do this quite simply like this, using the `$i` added to the `name=gender` to get `name=gender0` `name=gender1` etc

```
<?php
echo '<form method="post" action="index.php">';
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){

    echo 'Male <input type="radio" name="gender' . $i . '" value="Male">Female 
         <input type="radio" name="gender' . $i . '" value="Female"><br>';
}
echo '<input type="submit" value="submit" name="test"></form>

?>
```

Comment: I have button in which user can add more pairs ,so this will be applicabale in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Your input name is same for all the radio's thats why only one is option selected, try with different name for each radio or use checkboxes

```
<?php
echo '<form method="post" action="index.php">';
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){

    echo 'Male <input type="radio" name="gender_'.$i.'[]" value="Male">Female <input type="radio" name="gender_'.$i.'[]" value="Female"><br>';
}
echo '<input type="submit" value="submit" name="test"></form>';

?>
```